# How add declension of nouns based on numeral argument value

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate

I know that in Magenta version 2 and above, the option for declension of nouns based on the numerical value of the argument is added:

%1 [%1|cat|cats] -> 1 cat / 2 cats

But I don’t understand how and where to add it. 
Can you help?